# Custom UIStoryBoardSegue to zoom in

Tags: ios5

The way that I want this app's UI segues to function is that when the user taps on part of the screen, it zooms in to give detail on that part of the screen, but I'll probably want to use a different uiviewcontroller to manage that because it will do different things than the zoomed out view controller. Is the way to do this using the UIViewController's `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` method and a `CGAffineTransform`? Or is there another way that I haven't seen yet?

Comment: Nothing yet, I have a feeling that you could accomplish it using a custom Container View Controller but I haven't looked into it much.

Answer (score 2):

I found a good tutorial on this in *Learning iPad Programming* by Turner and Harrington. It really helped me see how custom segues work.

http://books.google.com/books?id=Xd5Z8K3aiIwC&q=uistoryboardsegue#v=snippet&q=(void)perform&f=false

You can get the gist of it in the preview on google books, but if you really find it useful you might want to buy the book.